# Issue in Rendering Sub-menu component in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

topNavigation.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import SubMenu from './subMenu';



class Navigation extends Component {

  state = {
    mainCategory: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3030/topCategory')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.express);
        this.setState({
          mainCategory: res.data.express.catalogGroupView
        })
      })
  }



  render() {

    const { mainCategory } = this.state;
    return mainCategory.map(navList => {
      return (

        <ul className="header">
          <li key={navList.uniqueID}> <button className="dropbtn ">{navList.name}</button>
          <SubMenu below={this.props.navList.catalogGroupView}/>

          </li>
        </ul>

      )

    })

  }


}

export default Navigation;
```

I'm new to react and trying to make an ecommerce website. I have designed the homepage. For the navigation, I have used an external api
 http://149.129.128.3:3737/search/resources/store/1/categoryview/@top?depthAndLimit=-1,-1,-1,-1

and mapped the response.

If I use the below code in place of 
SubMenu component it works

```
<ul>
                {console.log(navList.catalogGroupView)}
                {
                  navList.catalogGroupView.map(sub=> {
                    return <li key={sub.uniqueID}> <button>{sub.name}</button></li>
                    })
                }
              </ul>
```

But as per the url endpoint response there are more sub categories which I'm unable to map.

I thought of creating a separate component to display the sub menu items. But whenever I use this code it doesn't work.

Submenu.js component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class SubMenu extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            subCategory: []
        };
    }

    render() {


        return subCategory.map(sub => {

            return (
                <ul>
                    <li key={sub.uniqueID}> <button>{sub.name}</button></li>
                </ul>

            )
        })

    }

}

export default SubMenu;
```

Can somebody please help me on this. I would be grateful. I'm not getting where I got wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access subCategory of state. Here is the working part:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class SubMenu extends Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        subCategory: []
    };
}

render() {
    const { subCategory } = this.state; // you should've add this part

    return subCategory.map(sub => {

        return (
            <ul>
                <li key={sub.uniqueID}> <button>{sub.name}</button></li>
            </ul>

        )
    })

}

}

export default SubMenu;
```

**UPDATE** 
Over here:

```
<SubMenu below={this.props.navList.catalogGroupView}/>
```

You're trying to access prop, which doesn't exist, so you should do it that way:

```
<SubMenu below={navList.catalogGroupView}/>
```

And then In Submenu, you should map over the props, not state, because your state always will be empty array(because you're not setting it). And you don't need to use state in that case, because you just need to iterate over array. So here is the code of Submenu:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class SubMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        const {below} = this.props;
        return below.map(sub => {

            return (
                <ul>
                    <li key={sub.uniqueID}> <button>{sub.name}</button></li>
                </ul>

            )
        })

    }

}

export default SubMenu;
```

And theoretically working code of topNavigation.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import SubMenu from './subMenu';



class Navigation extends Component {

  state = {
    mainCategory: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3030/topCategory')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.express);
        this.setState({
          mainCategory: res.data.express.catalogGroupView
        })
      })
  }



  render() {

    const { mainCategory } = this.state;
    return mainCategory.map(navList => {
      return (

        <ul className="header">
          <li key={navList.uniqueID}> <button className="dropbtn ">{navList.name}</button>
          <SubMenu below={navList.catalogGroupView}/> 

          </li>
        </ul>

      )

    })

  }


}

export default Navigation;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting a error in topNavigation.js. I have attached the screen shot of it.

Comment: @Shaswati Bhattacharyya Could you please provide the code inside of topNavigation.js file. I can't see it in one of the files screenshots above.

Comment: I have edited my question and you can see the topNavigation.js Code

Comment: @Shaswati Bhattacharyya I can't quite understand, why in latest screen shot with error, it indicated that you're trying to access props:   <Submenu below={this.props.navList.catalogGroupView} /> on line 33, but in the code of topNavigation.js there is different piece of code: <SubMenu below={navList.catalogGroupView}/>. Could you please tell me, which one right one?

Comment: I have updated the question and attached everything. Can you now get an idea

Comment: Thank You So Much. But I have a doubt. There are more levels of categories inside. So, what needs to be done as per the response of API endpoint which i have shared. Can you please help me on this.